# Sum of elements of a 2d list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sum, iterator

I have a 2D list

`a = [[1,2], [3,4] ...]`

I want to do something like this:
1+3 and 2+4 and store result in another array

`b = [4, 6]`

Like 0th element of array at index 0 which is 1, added with 0th element of array at index 1 which is 3, and 2 added with 4, and so on.

How can I do this, without looping or generators as looping over a large list is comparatively slower than sum and zip functions.

Comment: consider showing the code that reflects your effort so far

Answer (score 1):

Using just `sum` and `zip` as you mention, however `zip` still returns a generator, which is memory efficient, not sure why you think otherwise.

```
list(map(sum, (zip(*a))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't worry about memory, but looping over a very large list is computationally very expensive.. :)